# VueJs : Button click is only worked when click twice

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have written some code as below. Using this code, button click is only work when i click two second time. Issue is only happened when i write something in text box and the click on button. After write something in textbox and click anywhere then after button click worked on one click otherwise it need to click two time for call the method.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="newuser" @keyup.enter="addarray"/>
    <button @click="addarray">Add New</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'computed',
  data() {
    return{
      newuser: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addarray() {
      alert('click');
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: use `form` instead of `div`, the `enter` is a default browser event

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jOmmoQB), using Chrome 91 on macOS Big Sur. What's your environment?

Comment: tony, i can see the same issue in your provided codepen link. Please write something in textbox & click on button

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you're talking about. I typed into the textbox, and clicked the button. The alert appears on a single click every time I try.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `div` for your form not a `form`, the `@keyup.enter` event will prevent the first click event.

use `form` for your form, submit the form when client tap enter on keyborad is a default event of `form`.

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data(){
        return{
            newuser:''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addarray(){
            alert('click');
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<main id="app">
    <form @submit.prevent="addarray">
        <input v-model="newuser"/>
        <button type="submit">Add New</button>
    </form>
</main>
```

what's more, `form` is more friendly for the disabled

Comment: Thanks but i have also tried to removed @keyup.enter from input but still not working of my first click. is mandatory to use the form for single button click?

Comment: tbh I tried his example in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/347ypvzo46?file=/src/layout.vue) and it works perfectly fine, so I don't see why the form tag would make any difference either.

Comment: @Camit1dk yeah, whether it is considered from accessibility or SEO, `form` is much more better than `div` in this situation

Comment: Braks, i have tried same code in your provide sandbox link, its also not work their. It's need to click two times on button after add any text in textbox. Can you verify.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I had it like this:

```
@click="doStuff('unitPrefix', (index + 1))"
```

I put window.console.log inside the doStuff() function. It only triggered when clicked second time. What fixed for me was to add the .stop modifier:

```
@click.stop="doStuff('unitPrefix', (index + 1))"
```

Now it triggers on every press for me. Posting this because first hit on google and nobody told about this variant.